# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, instagram

Доброго времени суток всем читающим. Столкнулся с такой проблемой "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'"
(сразу хочу сказать, что использую python 2-й день и для меня все очевидные вещи не очевидны)

Сама ошибка происходит вот в этом куске кода -

```
while len(pers) < all:
    num_scroll += 1
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", element)

    if num_scroll % 10 == 0:
        print("!")
        #Сохранение пользователей в массив
        persons = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a").text
        for i in range(len(persons)):
            pers.append(str(persons[i].get_attribute('href')))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
xpath = "/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a"
persons = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
for person in persons:
    pers.append(person.get_attribute('href'))
```

---

**PS.**

- Метод `find_element_by_xpath` вернет первое совпадение, а вам, похоже, нужны все поэтому используйте `find_elements_by_xpath`
- У строк действительно нет атрибута `get_attribute`, а в `persons[i]` у вас строка, т.к. в `persons = browser.find_element_by_xpath(...).text` будет строка, а перебирая символы этой строки тоже получите строку `persons[i].get_attribute('href')`
- Списки в питоне можно перебирать без индексов, через простую итерацию `for person in persons:`

Comment: Спасибо, что есть такие люди как Вы! Ошибка пропала)

Comment: @ИгорьХмелевский, пожалуйста, и не забывайте, что тут принято [поблагодарить автора ответа, через голосование за ответ или отметки его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать `.text()`. Насколько я помню, там возможно использование `html()`.